# Jenkins Pipeline Stage View Adding Description

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

In Jenkins if you go to Pipeline->Full Stage View you go the page that look like the one below.  How do I add a description to that?  I don't see any options to do anything to that page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a multibranch pipeline or a groovy script you can change the description from Jenkins instance

```
import hudson.model.*
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(<project_name>).getItem(<branch>).description =  "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26522 might be what you want to be able to annotate a stage with some text. Also look at the bugs which are referenced by this bug to see other options.

Comment: I don't want to annotate stage.  I want to put some description for the pipeline in the stage view page